# How to create a circular progress bar with rounded corners

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to figure out how to round off the corners of my circular progress bar. Creating the progress bar was fairly easy, however, I can't find a way to round off the corners on each side of the bar.

Here is my drawable circular_progress_bar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="270" android:toDegrees="270">
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="2.55"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thickness="5dp"
                android:useLevel="true">
                <gradient
                    android:type="sweep"
                    android:startColor="#ff963c"
                    android:endColor="#ff4641"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="211dp">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="1000"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="7dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#ff963c" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate>
            <inset android:insetBottom="211dp">
                <shape
                    android:innerRadiusRatio="1000"
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:thickness="5dp"
                    android:useLevel="false">
                    <solid android:color="#ff4641" />
                </shape>
            </inset>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And here is a snippet of my activity_main.xml:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="86"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="114dp" />
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: I have seen this problem solved by drawing a _circle_ at the start and end of the progress-bar. This might be an issue with your gradient color however.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing. It's not an issue with my gradient color.

Comment: @TheThugger 
1) Pretty good library https://github.com/lopspower/CircularProgressBar
You can open CircularProgressBar view source code and modify it!

2) I see that you copy code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52041905/how-to-make-round-corners-for-a-ring-shape-in-android-drawable
If you really don't want to create a custom view, change width and height of your ProgressBar to 250dp and then change progressBar size with scaleX and scaleY attributes. But I suggest you to use custom view or library, because it's more flexible.

Comment: https://github.com/korre/android-circular-progress-bar use this easy to use library